# Ошибка при старте программы с модулем slate 'module' object has no attribute 'PDF'

Tags: python

При старте программы выдает ошибку

> 'module' object has no attribute 'PDF'

Вот такой код

```
import slate
def extract_text_from_pdf(pdf_path):
   with open(pdf_path) as fh:
      document = slate.PDF(fh, password='', just_text=1)
   for page in document:
      print(page)
if __name__ == '__main__':
   extract_text_from_pdf('sample.pdf')
```

установил slate через pip

Comment: попробуйте `from slate import PDF`

Comment: попробовал, выдает "cannot import name PDF"

Comment: Нет ли у вас в одной папке с вашим скриптом файла с именем slate.py ?